# Volley JsonArrayRequest want to parse Json response but problem how to handle array response?

Tags: android, arrays, json

i am new in this development
here i want to get "Category", and according to category wants to get
"Title" &  "Price"
i already generated pojo classes

```
 Item items = gson.fromJson(response,Item.class);
 JSONArray json = new JSONArray(response);
```

> //TODO: PARSE category list and CATEGORY's : TITLE, PRICE that is
> items

actually i want it in a recycler adapter

```
> Response: [{"category": "Espresso & Coffee",
>            "items": [{"title": "Vacuum Coffee",
>                       "size": [{
>                           "label": "medium",
>                           "price": 125
>                       }]}],
>            }]
```

Comment: what are the fields you are trying to parse??

Comment: i wants to get "Category"  and  According to category its  "Titles" and "Price"  i m using RecyclerView to Show all three Fields.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got stuck in the same situation as you did a while ago and ended up handling the json manually instead of gson. Instead of using JsonArrayRequest, try JsonObjectRequest.

After, get each array by 'chopping' up the returns like this:

```
JsonArray c = response.getJSONArray("array");
```

Then you attain the values stored within the array by going through a for loop with the limit `i<c.length().`

However, since you have an arrray with the array you'd be doing something along this line:

```
for(int i=0; i<c.length(); i++){
//populates the array, in your case, jsonarray size = 4
JSONObject jsonObject = c.getJSONObject(i);
String cat= jsonObject.getString("category"); //gets category String
JSONArray items = jsonObject.getJSONArray("items");
....
```

here, you write an inner loop in order to get the array items in your object....i hope i'm helping you solve the problem instead of confusing you, lol. If you require an example, here's one which helped me out in figuring which goes where : https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Rotten-Tomatoes-Networking-Tutorial

Comment: thanks @Sarbinar u r right...      Nor for Size Array I will use this Items Array  and can get  JSONObject jsonObject1 = items.getJSONObject(j);
String title = jsonObject1.getString("title");                                              JSONArray sizes = jsonObject1.getJSONArray("Size");

Comment: yup! thats the gist of it--much simpler than relying on other libraries to handle your data, unless your data structure is a simple one. most of the time gson is a downright pain to work with

Comment: can u tell me how to show "price" with category in recyclerview  any Approach

Comment: i'm assuming you're able to get the jsonarray 'items'. Since 'size' is an object nested within 'items', you get the object'size' by nested for loop. 

for(int h=0; h<items.length;h++){
JsonArray size = items.getJsonObject("size");
....
...//its the same as getting an array
...
}

as for recycler view population, refer to the rottentomatoes API tutorial i've linked. What you need to do is to populated the information you've grabbed from JSON in a model class and fill the recycler view that way.